# Huge Web App With Memory Leak in IE 6

Tags: memory-leaks, internet-explorer-6

I have a huge web app that is having issues with memory leak in IE 6.

Fixing a memory leak in a 5 line code sample that demonstrates the problem is easy.

But if I have a very huge application, where should a start from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [Drip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ieleak).  That usually takes the guesswork out of IE memory leaks.

If for some reason Drip doesn't find it, take a close look at any JavaScript code that works with events.  That is almost always the source of any significant memory leak in a browser.

Destroying a DOM element with handlers attached to it, without removing those handlers first, will prevent the memory associated with those handlers from being recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Does the application use a lot of JavaScript?

If it does, then one thing I've found that helps for avoiding memory leaks is to make sure you're using a JavaScript framework such as Prototype or jQuery because they have tried and tested event-handling code that doesn't leak memory.

- IE6 can also leak memory if you have [circular references to DOM objects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830555/)
- Also try this [JavaScript Memory Leak Detector](http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector.aspx) and see if you can diagnose where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the memory leak problem in IE7. The idea is to dispose/set to null all expando-properties on all DOM nodes at unloading the page. This worked for me. You may find it useful.

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">

function disposeAll() {
    if (window.document.all) {
        for (var index = 0; index < window.document.all.length; index++) {
            try { dispose(window.document.all[index], []); } catch (e) { debugger; }
        }
    }
    dispose(window.document.body, []);
    dispose(window.document, []);
    dispose(window, []);
    window.disposeAll = null;
    window.dispose = null;
    window.onunload = null;
}

function dispose(something, map) {
    if (something == null) return;
    if (something.dispose && typeof (something.dispose) == 'function') {
        try { something.dispose(); } catch (e) { debugger; }
    }
    map.push(something);
    for (var key in something) {
        var value = null;
        try { value = something[key]; } catch (e) { };
        if (value == null || value == dispose || value == disposeAll) continue;

        var processed = null;
        for (var index = 0; index < map.length; index++) {
            if (map[index] === value) {
                processed = value;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (processed != null) continue;
        var constructor = value.constructor;
        if (constructor == Object || constructor == Array) {
            try { dispose(value, map); } catch (e) { debugger; }
        }
        if (constructor == Object || constructor == Array || constructor == Function) {
            try { something[key] = null; } catch (e) { debugger; }
        }
    }
    map.pop();
}

(function() {
    var previousUnloadHandler = window.onunload;
    if (previousUnloadHandler == null) {
        window.onunload = disposeAll;
    } else {
        window.onunload = function() {
            previousUnloadHandler.apply(this, arguments); // <== HERE YOU MAY WANT TO HAVE AN "IF" TO MAKE SURE THE ORIGINAL UNLOAD EVENT WASN'T CANCELLED
            disposeAll();
            previousUnloadHandler = null;
        };
    }
}());

</script>
<![endif]-->
```

You may want to remove all "debugger;" statements if you don't feel like dealing with some occasional exceptions.